# SSIS - Converting unformatted strings dates to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis

I'm trying to convert the string column `[mydate]` to a date, and I would like to use the `Derived Column Transformation`. The problem is this that my dates are like `'1/10/2015'`, `'1/1/2015'`, `'11/1/2015'` and `'11/9/2015'`. So the format can change between `D/MM/YYYY`, `D/M/YYYY`, `DD/M/YYYY`, and `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Can you guide me in creating the expression for the `Derived Column Transformation`?

I tried to use something like this:

```
(DT_DATE)(ISNULL([mydate]) ==  FALSE  ? (RIGHT([mydate],4) + "-" + "2" + "-" + LEFT([mydate],1)) : [mydate])
```

Comment: Change the field type in the Flat file source instead of trying to convert it aftewards. You *can* specify that a specific field is a date with a certain format. BTW dates do not have formats, they are binary values. You don't need to convert them to `yyyy-MM-dd` if you are going to use and store them as dates

Comment: I try that initially but here the issue in that the SQL saves the date like this 

2015-10-30   <- flat file source was 30/10/2015
2015-03-11   <- flat file source was 3/11/2015

it swapped the month and day (as my server machine is set to THAI which uses MM/DD/YYYY)
do you know the reason

Comment: What issue? It's impossible to help if you don't explain what the issue actually is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
[link](http://s24.postimg.org/mqhjo1r6d/Capture.jpg) SQL import screenshot
when i import as you suggested my system swaps the month and day in different positions possibly because of my server regional settings, that's why I try to do the **Derived column Transformation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is quite tricky since we're not only dealing with unformatted String dates but they are also not in the region netural `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

To fix this, we can use the follwing expression for the `Derived Column`:

```
RIGHT([mydate],4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([mydate],FINDSTRING([mydate],"/",1) + 1,FINDSTRING([mydate],"/",2) - FINDSTRING([mydate],"/",1) - 1) + "/" + SUBSTRING([mydate],1,FINDSTRING([mydate],"/",1) - 1)
```

The expression is quite long but what it is doing is taking the values (month, day, year) between the forward slashes `/` and concatenating them into a format that resembles `YYYY/MM/DD` that can then be converted in SSIS using a `Data Conversion` transformation. This avoids the error of dealing with the change in length in dates like `1/1/2000` and `10/10/2000`.

The output of the derived column was named `YYYYMMDD` and this value was then passed into a `Data Conversion` transformation that has output `Date Converted YYYYMMDD` as seen below.

[image: date conversion from improper string into proper date]

The `Data Conversion` task is simply doing the follwing:

[image: data conversion task of converted date]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Replace to solve this
Replace(ColumnName,"/","-")